# How to fill image's holes located at the boundaries of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to remove all holes in a binarized image, including the ones located at the boundaries of this image.

I only manage to fill holes not touching the boundaries. So far, to remove holes I find contours with OpenCV `findContours` method, and then fill them with OpenCV "drawContours" function.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
contour, hier = cv2.findContours(ddwi.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   for cnt in contour:
        cv2.drawContours(ddwi, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)
```

Any idea of how to get rid of the holes at the boundaries ?

[image]

Comment: This would set all pixels to foreground. I presume this is not what you meant, so please share your definition of “hole”, and preferably include an example image and the expected output.

Comment: So you are trying to remove the smaller holes touching the image edge. That large black area in your example image has the same properties as the smaller ones, except for the size. So you can set a threshold for size, like you did in your answer below. Well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am a new stackoverflow contributor, I cannot post images yet unfortunately.
To make an idea of what my image is about, it looks like this [one](https://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14019666614662045.png)

(image n°5: - Fill holes + opening morphological operations to remove small noise blobs)

I found a solution of my problem using first contour detection and filling with opencv, and then skimage "morphology.remove_small_holes" function enabled me to fill holes at the boundary of image. Here is the code:

```
# fill holes
    contour, hier = cv2.findContours(ddwi.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS)
    for cnt in contour:
        cv2.drawContours(ddwi, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)

    # remove residual small holes at the boundary of image
    from skimage import morphology
    ddwi = morphology.remove_small_holes(ddwi.astype(np.uint8))
    ddwi = 255 * ddwi.astype(np.uint8)
```